# Translating code from JS to C#. I don't understand what this function does

Tags: javascript, c#

`

```
    const yandexRequests = (function() {
      var protoRequest = new protobuf.Type("VideoTranslationRequest").add(new protobuf.Field("url", 3, "string")).add(new protobuf.Field("deviceId", 4, "string")).add(new protobuf.Field("unknown0", 5, "int32")).add(new protobuf.Field("unknown1", 6, "fixed64")).add(new protobuf.Field("unknown2", 7, "int32")).add(new protobuf.Field("language", 8, "string")).add(new protobuf.Field("unknown3", 9, "int32")).add(new protobuf.Field("unknown4", 10, "int32"));
      var protoResponse = new protobuf.Type("VideoTranslationResponse").add(new protobuf.Field("url", 1, "string")).add(new protobuf.Field("status", 4, "int32"));
      new protobuf.Root().define("yandex").add(protoRequest).add(protoResponse);
      return {
          encodeRequest: function(url, deviceId, unknown1) {
              return protoRequest.encode({url: url, deviceId: deviceId, unknown0: 1, unknown1: unknown1, unknown2: 1, language: "en", unknown3: 0, unknown4: 0}).finish();
          },
          decodeResponse: function(response) {
              return protoResponse.decode(new Uint8Array(response));
          }
      };
  })();
```

var body = yandexRequests.encodeRequest(url, deviceId, unknown1);
`

I don't understand what this function does.

Answer (score 0):

It returns an object that contains two functions: `encodeRequest` and `decodeResponse`. Those functions call `protoRequest.encode` and `protoResponse.decode` when they are called.

`protobuf` is a Google thing I think: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/protobuf/index.htm, but I didn't think they had a JavaScript version, so maybe it's a custom job.